# Multiple HTML Background Colors

Tags: html, background, color-scheme

First, I like to thank everybody who has been patient with all of my web design questions. I have actually finished typing up my first HTML web page. I have everything pretty much how I envisioned it to be (almost). Now I am trying to add some colors to the background. Since I am still learning HTML, I don't want to get too far ahead of myself but I still want the background to be popping. I figured 3 horizontal colors should be fine. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `background-image: linear-gradient` to produce multiple different background colors like so:

**3 colors**

```css
body{

    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,
         #F6D6A8 33.3%,
        #F5BA55 33.3%, #F5BA55 66.6%,
        #F09741 66.6%, #F09741 99.9%);
}
```

**2 colors**

```css
body{

    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,
        #e1ecf3 50%, #e1ecf3 50%,
        #F5BA55 50%, #F5BA55 50%);
}
```

**Multiple colors**

```css
body{

    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,
        #F6D6A8 20%,
        #F5BA55 20%, #F5BA55 40%,
        #F09741 40%, #F09741 60%,
        #327AB2 60%, #327AB2 80%,
        #3A94F6 80%);
}
```